# textview not showing long values

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, long-integer

I am implementing a timer and following is the code for that,
**Main Activity**

```
public class DepthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_depth);
        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    long startTime;
    boolean showingFirst = true;

    public void generate(View view) {
        if(showingFirst 
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            showingFirst = false;
        } else {
            long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            TextView myText = findViewById(R.id.tv);
            myText.setText(String.valueOf(difference));
            showingFirst = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="237dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="start/stop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.83"
    android:onClick="generate"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But when i click the button second time it doesnt show "long dffrence" and textview remains blank.
It is not also showing any error in log
please help and thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At manifest you declare the `clickListener` from `Button` as `generate()`.

But at Activity's `onCreate`, you override it `findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);`.

Remove `findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);` from `onCreate` or call `generate(v)` inside `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
 findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(this);
```

from onCreate()

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_depth);
    }
```

So that onClick will handle by layout xml file.